How can I fix one user account when the Finder Tags don’t show in the contextual menu?
I’m experiencing an issue with tags in Finder on macOS Sonoma 14.5.
My main account has this issue. Creating a new account, the tags work fine.
The tags are now invisible (not displayed)  when I right-click.

I tried using Safe Mode, but the problem persisted. Initially, I thought this issue might only affect OneDrive files, but it turned out to be present with every file and folder. Interestingly, I can still tag files and folders using the Finder menu, but not through right-clicking.
What I tried:

Reinstalling macOS
Erasing and recovering data using Time Machine.

Is it possible to find the problem here and fix the problem user account?

After trying various troubleshooting steps, I managed to resolve the issue. Here’s how I fixed it: To display tags in the context menu on macOS, at least one tag must be added to the favourite tags list in the Finder setting. Initially, my tags were like this. One can see there was nothing in the favourite list, and hence, the tags... did not show up in the context menu.

Here’s how you can fix this:

Open Finder.

Go to Finder > Settings... > Tags.


Drag at least one tag from the list into the favourite tags section.

Once a tag is added to the favourite tags list, it will appear in the context menu when you right-click on files or folders in Finder (see the screenshot).



At least one tag is in the favourite list, which ensures that tags are displayed correctly in the context menu of macOS Finder. This step effectively resolved the issue I was experiencing.
Why was the problem not showing up in the new user?

By default, there are colour tags, and all these colour tags are available in the favourite list. That is the reaso when one makes a new user, this problem can not appear.

